# Please tell me where is my 8GB why it is showing my / is full

Tags: 11.10

I'm using ubuntu 11.10. When I do **df -h** it shows me **below image data:**

[image]

**My problem is my drive /dev/xvda1 is showing 100% used.**

But when I run **sudo du -ch**

It shows 13GB used.

12 GB in /mnt

1 GB in /

I cann't find my 8 GB in /dev/xvda1

I run php + rails in ubuntu. I deleted all log files also. 
**Please tell me where is my 8GB why it is showing my / is full**

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to run `du -ch /`?  In my Ubuntu I get different results using `du -ch /` and using `du -ch`

Comment: Alberto I run the command but still the same problem. :(

Comment: @manish nautiyal, the du command lists disk usage, and won't do anything to fix the problem.  you would need to read the output and see what folders are taking up the most space.

Comment: @ImaginaryRobots I have check each and every folders. It not showing too much space consumed. I d'nt know why this is happen :(